# Matching color, brightness and contrast of multiple images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I created a texture for a *3d mapping*. I made it joining the images (photos, that had been taken during different lighting conditions). Every horizontal image has *slightly different color, brightness and contrast*. My question is how to unify them?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "Match Color" under "Image" and then "Adjustments."

You'll need two images though, so save a copy of the image, called something like "Original_Colors.jpg" and then work in a second one. There's a really good tutorial here:

http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/match-color/

In your case, you won't have to be super careful with the selection areas, so this should be a very easy thing to accomplish.

With about 30 seconds work, I made this from your art:

[image]

With a little care and attention, you should be able to do much better. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man. Maybe it's not perfect, but it works good!

Comment: You are welcome! With some practice and tweaks, it works well. That tutorial I linked to is a good source of info.